# How to return the first value from groups in one database table, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table called `photos` in a MySQL database that contains photo filenames and other related info. Structure as follows:

```
+----------+------------+-------------+
| photo_id | gallery_id | photo_fname |
|----------|------------|-------------|
|     1    |      1     |  DSC2001    |
|     2    |      1     |  DSC2002    |
|     3    |      1     |  DSC2003    |
|     4    |      2     |  DSC2004    |
|     5    |      2     |  DSC2005    |
|     6    |      2     |  DSC2006    |
|     7    |      3     |  DSC2007    |
|     8    |      3     |  DSC2008    |
|     9    |      3     |  DSC2009    |
+----------+------------+-------------+
```

What I want to do is write a query that returns the first photo filename for each gallery, as follows:

```
+----------+------------+-------------+
| photo_id | gallery_id | photo_fname |
|----------|------------|-------------|
|     1    |      1     |  DSC2001    |
|     4    |      2     |  DSC2004    |
|     7    |      3     |  DSC2007    |
+----------+------------+-------------+
```

I researched this until my headache overcame me last night and although I found similar questions, they didn't seem to me to be looking to do the exact same thing. I tried subqueries, I tried the sample code from other posts here but couldn't make it work.  Either due to brain fog or just not finding the right solution.

I just want to return the results as shown above, nothing more.

Many thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**
My apologies, the table name is photos, FWIW.

Secondly, all I really want is the filename, not the photo or gallery Id, I just included those for visual clarity. I apologize if that caused confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE photo_id IN ( SELECT MIN(photo_id) 
                    FROM YourTable
                    GROUP BY gallery_id)
```

### [See a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f433/2)

For your updated question:

```
SELECT photo_fname
FROM photos
WHERE photo_id IN ( SELECT MIN(photo_id) 
                    FROM photos
                    GROUP BY gallery_id)
```

Comment: I viewed the Fiddle, but when I use the code, it returns the same filename for each item, in this case, `DSC2001`. I'm not certain what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: @wordman That is weird, are you sure that you are using the same query?

Comment: I screwed up, yes, it works.My problem is that I have two queries going, one pulls thumbnails for display, and the other is your query. In order to auto-generate the thumbnail page I have a do / while loop that populates the page just fine, except only the first filename is ever used because of the loop. I need to figure out my loops now. But your query is spot on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way using inner join

```
SELECT
  m.*
FROM sparkles as m
  INNER JOIN (SELECT
        photo_id,
        MIN(photo_id)
          FROM sparkles
          GROUP BY gallery_id) as l
    on l.photo_id = m.photo_id
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f433/7)

Comment: This seems a lot more complicated than Lamak's answer.

Comment: Well @njk this is more efficient joins are always faster than where in cases like these

Comment: This answer has a couple of issues. First, you are grouping by `photo_id` and doing an aggregation on that same column. And you didn't put an alias on the `MIN`. And, though it might be true most of the times, *joins are always faster than where* is not really correct

Comment: Lamak's [execution plan](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f433/9) vs. Raheel's [execution plan](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f433/11)

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT photo_id, gallery_id, photo_frame
FROM ...
GROUP BY photo_id, gallery_id
```

by default, mysql will return the FIRST non-grouped value it encounters in the DB for any non-aggregated fields in the field list.

Answer (score -2):

```
Select * from tablename group by gallery_id;       ?
```

Comment: That grabs everything, where what @Lamak offered did the trick. Check out his solution, it's quite clever although I'm still going over it to fully understand it.